# AS3 keyboard input assign to child swf

Tags: actionscript-3

**can i assign a keyboard eventlistener in a child swf inside of another swf?**

cause i know if a swf inside of swf still only have one stage. cause the parent swf just like a loader container, i want the child swf to have the keyboard event listener.

Thanks

Comment: Should take up all of about 5 minutes to try it out..

Comment: I did Marty, but it give me error message when i put
stage.addEventListener(); in the child swf
i understand there is only one stage, and you can't assign a stage to a child. but is there a way you can get around this?

Comment: Maybe try something like MovieClip(root).stage.addEventListener()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you loading the child swf? It may be a security issue. Possibly due to loaderContext or something.